# Print loss values every epoch in TF 2.x

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I wrote custom loss function in TF 2.3 where the loss is comprised of several sub-losses, since I want to track the sub-losses I've printed them using `tf.print`:

```
def custom_loss_envelop(model_inputs,  model, num_bound,model_outputs,lambda_, ener):
    def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
     l1 = ....
     l2 = ....
     l3 = ....
     tf.print("l1:",tf.math.round(l1 * 100)/100,", l2:", tf.math.round(l2 * 100) / 100,
        ", l3:", tf.math.round(l3 * 100) / 100,
        ", l4:", tf.math.round(l4 * 100) / 100)
        loss = l1 + l2 + l3 + l4
        return loss
    return custom_loss
```

The problem is that this code prints the losses every batch while I want it only every epoch.
Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `keras.callbacks.Callback()` class with this defined function:

```
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    keys = list(logs.keys()) 
    # you could do more here ...            
    print("End epoch {} of training; got log keys: {}".format(epoch, keys))
```

Noting that end of epoch will work during training only.
Look at some other options in documentation
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback?hl=en

Comment: I don't think this will save the sublosses, only the final loss is saved

Comment: `on_epoch_end` will give you the facility to do whatever you want to do so you could simply add your code inside. You may check updated sample